# how do i check typeof prop in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```js
const test = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
};

type KEYS = keyof typeof test;

const getType = (props: KEYS | string) => {
 const receivedType =
    test[props] === typeof test
      ? test[recordType]
      : '4';
}
```

i want to check if props is typeof test i will return test[props]
but props doesn't include typeof test i want to return 4

I don't know how to deal with the string case.

what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're trying to check if the argument `props` is a key of the object `test`. You can't check types during runtime like in `test[props] === typeof test`.

But something like this will check if `props` is a key of the object `test`

```js
const test = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
};

type KEYS = keyof typeof test;

const getType = (props: KEYS | string) => {
  const isKey = Object.keys(test).includes(props);
  const receivedType = isKey ? test[props] : '4';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first observation is that the union `KEYS | string` will just simplify to `string`. If you want to provide hints about the correct properties to pass in but still allow any `string` you can use  `KEYS | (string & {})` which will not reduce to `string` (looks strange, is not documented, but works)

The second part is that since `test` has a type and you want to index it with any `string` you will need to use a type assertion to get it to work. Also for testing the property you could just use the `in` operator:

```
const getType = (props: KEYS | (string & {})) => {
 const receivedType =
    props in test
      ? (test as Record<string, string>)[props]
      : '4';
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQMYEMBcMA5AIyEA0WMARgYQEzmXC0DMjAvgNwYZQCeAB3gwA0gFEAmgGUUMANbw+IAGZxB8FXERRuGUJFgBzeFAAq62QAoBAJxACIBcdJgAfGJeg2AlmEMwAMnR2AEoQlAA+dCx9JBt4YHhvADd4ABNzIRRKbFt7CBhfLWgc7BgAfg8EJBwCgCUEkBs0gB4vX0MyGHa-CJCAbTyHAF1S7FoAFkJudiA)